# What is currently the best theoretical book (or notes) about Convolutional Neural Networks?

Tags: machine-learning

I have a degree in maths and i am interested in learning about Convolutional Neural Networks from a mathematical/ theory point of view. Can someone point me towards some resource.

I already have a basic knowledge of Convolutional Neural Networks (and other Neural Networks)

Comment: Best is a matter of opinion and preferences.

Comment: @YvesDaoust there are not many theoretical books on convolutional networks, hundreds in applied ML but in theory possibly only one or two.

Comment: What is best is a matter of opinion, which is generally out of the scope of this site.  See our [help/dont-ask].  What works best is to identify a list of (objectively evaluatable) requirements that a book must satisfy; and to do some research and show the list of books you've found and the extent to which they do or don't meet the listed requirements.  A good way to do research to identify potential books is to look at what textbooks are used in related courses at major universities, and look at Amazon reviews.

Comment: @KoenigLear: that is your opinion. In a single Web query I hit "Top 8 Books To Learn Convolutional Neural Networks". Telling which are "theoretical" is also a matter of opinion.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The top 8 best books you discuss are not theoretical  they're all about implementation.   Find one other than the one I answered that is about theory, if you can.   I agree with D..W that the question should focus on the criteria, which is "theory" and not implementation cookbooks.   Theory is the mathematical model that explain why/how it works rather than how to use it.

Comment: @KoenigLear: how do you prove it ? And how do you prove that there are not more on theory ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust.   I can tell you that they're implementation because they refer to specidfic technologies and framwork:Java,python, tensorflow.    The book I'm suggesting has no implementation/framework description whatsoever, it's pure mathematical models and analyisis.  If there's another book on theory I'd love to know and hence why I think the question is valid/useful.

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest Deep Learning from Ian Goodfellow, Yoshua Bengio and Aaron Courvile. It has a whole chapter on Convolutional Neural Networks and the background to all Neural Networks.     Furthermore the Bibliography has a list of key papers if you want to dig deeper or into recent developments.